# Set system date for selenium tests

Tags: testing, selenium, functional-testing

I have a Javascript script that should work on weekends and at nights and I want to test it with Selenium (yeah, I know about Jasmine, it's just easier to use Selenium for this project).

Is it possible to somehow change system (browser) dates to test the script without writing setters in the script for testing?

Comment: Since you mentioned that scripts runs during weekends and night....from where the Script is referring the date & Time???

Comment: @Anuragh27crony The script creates new Date() object and checks the date and time. I pass this object as an option now, so tests pass the date and time they need but I'm just curious whether it is possible to do it with Selenium only.

Comment: So i believe that ....that there is a Javascript function which takes  Date & time as input parameters and does some work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it Selenium way....You can invoke/Execute the Javascript functions Synchronously and Async way....

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
```

***Synchronous way***

```
js.ExecuteAsyncScript("Javascript_Function(Date_x,Time_Y)");
```

***Async - Way***

```
js.ExecuteScript("Javascript_Function(Date_x,Time_Y)");
```

I hope this helps...all the best :)